# How do I generate a MySQL view such that it show all objects in your heircachy

Tags: mysql, view, sql-view

I am trying to make a database with several people listed in the user database using MySQL. I am trying to make it so that it will list all the people in the database that he is under.

I also have a database Supervisors, which two foreign keys to users that show each person that person supervises. (Admin A supervises Manager A, Admin A supervises Manager B, Manager A supervises Employee A)

So for example, We have an Admin A, who supervise Manager A and Manager, who supervise Employee A and Employee B, respectfully. I want to know how can I make a such that The Admin A can generate a view to show the people who are under him (Manager A, Manager B, Employee A, and Employee B), but will not be able to see the people who he is not under, such Admin B and CEO.

Comment: if you can't get a view written, I can show a stored proc. Just let me know how many rows total, or at least the typical sub-tree height, ... if you don't get a view from someone

Comment: If it can't be done through a view, then a stored proc might work. I don't know how many rows totals, but the tree wouldn't be more then 6 layers high.

Comment: a view would be nice, as to suggest that a consolidated select statement, regardless of its complexity, is just one statement. I haven't seen this done by anyone yet, and I tend to answer it in a stored proc. We can wait